# Displaying records using SQL query from 2 or more combinations in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I am new to php and sql; i am writing a sql query to display records where the following logic follows:

**1.** There are 9 cells in sql table. I want to search records using combinations of  3 parameters. That are search between 2 dates, search in location and search in property category type.

**2.** Search criteria looks like this :

Date From : _________(date picker) -  Date Till:______________(date picker)

Location: Dropdown ( dehi, mumbai,.....,)

Property Category Type : Dropdown ( Residential, Commercial)

---

Results Combination Required:

a. All 3 combination True - *(User Fills the date, location, Prop Cat Type.)*

b. Either of the combination is True. *(User only fills either of one parameter.)*

c. Only 2 Combination are True. (User fills 2 parameter combination ie, date and location (or) location & property type (or) date & property type)

PROBLEM:
I can able to do only one combination....

Here is my sql query and page syntax.:

```
    if(isset($_POST['search'])){
$name=$_POST['search'];
$location=$_POST['select1'];
$date1=$_POST['d_dov1'];
$date2=$_POST['d_dov2'];
$categ=$_POST['category'];
 $query="SELECT * FROM customer WHERE d_loc='$location' OR d_dov BETWEEN '$date1' AND '$date2' OR d_cate='$categ'";

$sql_Q=mysql_query($query); }else{
$Q_select = "Select * from customer Order by id DESC";
$sql_Q = mysql_query($Q_select) or die(mysql_error());  }
```

Please help in this regard.

Comment: "*..I can able to do only one combination....*" Which combination you are able to do.?

Comment: Which format `$date1` and `$date2` are having and which format `d_dov` having in table ?

Comment: I am able to write 

SELECT * FROM customer WHERE d_loc='$location' OR d_dov BETWEEN '$date1' AND '$date2' OR d_cate='$categ'";
This is combination (b).

I want the sql query in which all 3 can give results.

Comment: $date1 and $date2 are in varchar in datebase and in UI we have applied datepicker to capture date

Comment: @NanaPartykar : Seems like you are quite a fan in here..! :D

Comment: I didn't get it @UmairShahYousafzai

Comment: @NanaPartykar : Sorry I forgot to write "of Nana Partaykar" in previous comment..! I hope you would understand now..!

Comment: Every Aspiring Actor's Idolize "Nana Patekar". And, I am one of them @UmairShahYousafzai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can concatenate your query and do this task.

```
if(isset($_POST['search'])){
$name=$_POST['search'];
$location=$_POST['select1'];
$date1=$_POST['d_dov1'];
$date2=$_POST['d_dov2'];
$categ=$_POST['category'];

$query="SELECT * FROM customer WHERE id!=0";
if($location!=''){
   $query.=" AND d_loc='$location'";
}
if($date1!='' && $date2!=''){
   $query.= " AND d_dov BETWEEN '$date1' AND '$date2'";
}
if($categ!=''){
  $query.= " AND d_cate='$categ'";
}
```

if you select all values you query concatenate.The idea behind using id!=0 is to concatenate the query.the id is the primary key of your table.

You can use **AND** or **OR** its depends on your need.